# How to handle an element if it has no name and no id properties?

Tags: javascript

I am using some elements (`input`, `select`, `textarea` etc.) to send data from client inputs to server via XHR(ajax).

While processing data and in sending process I give informations to user with modal dialog and block his screen.

After sent success and everythings done right, give "success info" and unblock his screen.

Also I must clean (reset) input fileds. I didn't use form, so I couldn't use `reset()`.

I try to doing this with the following JavaScript:

```
function hedefiSifirla(anacElementID) {
    var anacElement = (nY(anacElementID) ? nY(anacElementID) : anacElementID);

    for (xi, xiLen = anacElement.children.length; xi < xiLen; xi++) {
        var elm = anacElement.children[xi];

        if (elm.hasChildNodes()) {
            hedefiSifirla(elm)
        }

        if ((elm.tagName == 'input' && elm.type != 'checkbox') || elm.tagName == 'textarea') {
            alert(elm.id);
            elm.value = '';
        }

        if (elm.tagName == 'input' && elm.type == 'checkbox') {
            elm.checked = false;
            alert(elm.id);
        }

        if (elm.tagName == 'select') {
            elm.options.length = 0;
            alert(elm.id);
        }
    }
}
```

This didn't work with any error log. Where did i go wrong?

Comment: What do you mean "this didn't work with any error log"?  What happened? Was there any error produced in the console?

Comment: `How to handle an element if it has no name and no id properties?`: You can use [**querySelector()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) passing any valid CSS selector to get to the element. Works in all other browsers except IE7 and lower. You can also use [**querySelectorAll()**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.querySelectorAll) for multiple element matches but in IE8 it only alloows CSS2 selectors but works great in IE9.

Comment: There is no error thrown when i run the web page which includes this js. I expect to clean all data including elements like `input`, `select`,`textarea` with this function. I am using Chrome.

Comment: @FrançoisWahl is `querySelectorAll()` catch sub elements (grandchild) of an element?

Comment: Why not just use a `<form>` and `reset()` that?

Comment: @Bergi user must interact with elements and their values (also options). There is some ajax requests for user interactions. Also forms `reset()` doesn't clear `select` options added dynamically. But for now i'm going to put form and `reset()`. Thank you all.

Comment: @caglaror: `querySelectorAll` is the same as `querySelector` the only difference bing that `querySelectorAll` returns all elements matching your specified CSS selector while `querySelector` only returns the first one. For example `querySelector('#someElement input')` will return the first `input` within an element having `id="someElement"` it comes across. While `querySelectorAll('#myElement input')` returns all of the `inputs` found inside the element with `id="someElement"`. As both allow CSS selectors you can even do `querySelector('#myElement > input:first')` and so on.